# How to get multiple value as return type from a method in C#?

Tags: c#

Suppose in a C# class there is a method Like `_Abc(int a, int b)` usually it takes 2 parameters.

Is it possible to get 4 int values from `_Abc(int a, int b)` method as return?

Comment: Make a class out it and have send an object of that type. Main thing to remember is there is only one return type for any method. IF you want multiples, you can try returning an array, list, object, based on your specific need

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to return int[4] from a function with 2 parameters?

Comment: @JimmyThompson why would the return value be dependent on number of input parameters? Please see answers below on how to use out parameters. In case of just a return, i can have a function return anything it wants or it should.

Comment: @ryadavilli I understand what return types and out parameters are; just not what he meant by the question.

Answer (score 10):

You could return a [`Tuple<int, int, int, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd414846.aspx). Returning tuples as part of a public API isn't very informative however, so in that case I would create a class to hold the return values so you can name the values.

Comment: Tuples are fine, but unless you are the only one using this method, I prefer a custom type with properly named properties.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan - Yes, that's why I suggested the alternative of creating a class. It really depends on the usage. If it's a private method being called from one or two places I would probably use `Tuple`, otherwise create a struct or class.

Answer (score 9):

Though the answers so far (return a tuple, return a collection, return a custom class/struct, or use out parameters) are reasonable answers, a better answer is: **don't do that in the first place**. A method that returns four things is probably a badly-designed method.

Can you redesign the type so that you have, say, four different methods (or properties) each of which returns one thing? There may be a better pattern for you to use. Can you explain your scenario in more detail?

Answer (score 6):

You can return a custom type which is the most flexible and extensible approach.

```
public static Foo GetFoo(int a, int b)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.A = 1;
    foo.B = 2;
    foo.C = 3;
    foo.D = 4;
    return foo;
}
```

Here's the pseudo class

```
public class Foo
{
    public int A{ get; set; }
    public int B{ get; set; }
    public int C{ get; set; }
    public int D{ get; set; }
}
```

Another way (with .NET 4) is using a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

```
public static Tuple<int,int,int,int> GetFoo(int a, int b)
{
    return Tuple.Create(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Which is not so readable as the class approach since you read the properties in this way:

```
var values = GetFoo(1, 2);
int A = values.Item1;
int B = values.Item2;
int C = values.Item3;
int D = values.Item4;
```

So a tuple is somehwhat anonymous.

If you just want to return one or two additional parameters you can also use an [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) parameter as in the `TryParse` methods.

```
DateTime dt;
String str = "01.01.2013";
if(DateTime.TryParse(str, out dt))
{
    // so this method returns two variables:
    // a bool as return value and a DateTime as out parameter
    Console.WriteLine("Year: " + dt.Year);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the clean OOP approach. Tuples are also good, but unless the user of this method knows documentation to the letter, they can be really messy. OK in private methods though.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Lee's answer, You could add some `ref` or `out` parameters, ie:

```
_Abc(int a, int b, out int c, out int d, out int e, out int f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a function like this with out parameters.

```
public void _Abc(int a, int b, out res1, out res2, out res3, out res4)
   {
    res1 = 1;
    res2 = 2;
    res3 = 3;
    res4 = 4;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the method you can use out parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx

```
_Abc(int a, int b, out int c, out int d, out int e, out int f){
c=1;
d=2;
e=3;
f=4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return them as [out parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning 4 completely different things, then it would be best to create a new type.  For example, if you're returning the height, width, top, and bottom values of a newly created shape, then you should create a class that holds all of those values with the proper variable names.

If you're holding 4 of the same type of thing then it may make sense to put them all into a collection of some sort.  For example, if the four numbers represent the area of four different shapes then it would make sense to return a `List<int>` or an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need easy ans, right?

Try to understand this simple code (just copy and paste):

```
class Class1
{
    private List<int> _Abc(int a, int b)
    {
        // do job

        int x = 128, y = 256, z = 512;
        List<int> returns = new List<int>();
        returns.Add(x);
        returns.Add(y);
        returns.Add(z);

        return returns;
    }

    public void anotherMethod()
    {
        List<int> simple = new List<int>();
        simple = _Abc(55, 56);

        int[] _simple = simple.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < simple.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + _simple[i]);
        }
        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```